# How to duplicate operations & placeholders in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose I have two neural network model defined each with 1 input placeholder and 1 output tensor. From these 2 outputs I need 3 separate values.

```
inputs: i1, i2, outputs: o1, o2
a = 1
b = 2

v1 = session.run(o1, feed_dict={i1: a})
v2 = session.run(o1, feed_dict={i1: b})
v3 = session.run(o2, feed_dict={i2: a})
```

The problem is I need to feed these 3 values into a loss function so I can't do the above. I need to do

```
loss = session.run(L, feed_dict={i1: a, i1: b, i2:a })
```

I don't think I can do that but even if I could I would still have the ambiguity in later operations since o1 with input i1 is used differently than o1 with input i2.

I think it could be solved by having 2 input placeholders and 2 outputs in the first neural network. So given I already have a model is there a way to restructure the inputs and outputs so that I can accommodate this?

Visually I want to turn

```
i1 ---- (model) ----- o1
```

into

```
i1a                          o1a
  \                         /
   \                       /
    x ----- (model) ----- x        
   /                       \
  /                         \
i1b                          o1b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is right, you have to create 2 different placeholders i1a and i1b for your network 1, with two outputs o1a and o1b. Your visuals look great so here is my proposition:

```
i1a  ----- (model) -----  o1a
              |            
        shared weights                                  
              |            
i1b  ----- (model) -----  o1b
```

---

The proper way to do that is to duplicate your network by using `tf.get_variable()` for every variable with `reuse=True`.

```py
def create_variables():
  with tf.variable_scope('model'):
    w1 = tf.get_variable('w1', [1, 2])
    b1 = tf.get_variable('b1', [2])

def inference(input):
  with tf.variable_scope('model', reuse=True):
    w1 = tf.get_variable('w1')
    b1 = tf.get_variable('b1')
    output = tf.matmul(input, w1) + b1
  return output

create_variables()

i1a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3, 1])
o1a = inference(i1a)

i1b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3, 1])
o1b = inference(i1b)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(o1a - o1b)


with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  sess.run(loss, feed_dict={i1a: [[0.], [1.], [2.]], i1b: [[0.5], [1.5], [2.5]]})
```